# Is it possible to access a function's local variable from outside that function?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following code:

```
(function () {
  var secret = "a very secret string";
})();
```

Is it possible for any other scripts running on the page to access the variable `secret`? I know the end-user can easily access this variable by opening up the JavaScript debugger, but this is ok. My concern is that this script will be running as a third-party script and I don't want to leak any of the user's session information to the page that embeds my script.

Comment: no, unless you expose it in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, from within the javascript runtime that variable would be visible only to that function.  But if you have something that is truly secret, you can never trust that the client won't be able to access it.  Consider that some other script on that page could issue an XHR to re-download the .js file and parse it out that way (if it really wanted to).

Comment: Could they really XHR the script if I haven't set any CORS headers?

Comment: There are a lot of different things that you can _try_ to do to protect it, but if the browser can download the script, then something else can too.

Comment: @Max: You've said your script is being run as "third party" script on the page, which I take to mean that it's being loaded from a page that isn't in the same origin as your script. If so, then no, they couldn't, because the page's origin wouldn't match the origin of your .js file. If your script weren't being loaded cross-origin, then yes, they could, because it's the page's origin that matters.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The script is being dynamically generated per-user by injecting the cookie values into the script, since the user's cookie values will not be available on the consuming sites. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No. no access. But if a user try to debug this code, he can achieve the value using a breakpoint